# Assign value to a variable while passing it to a function in Go

Tags: go

I am pretty new to **Go** and I just wanted to know how do you **pass a value to a function while assigning it to a variable**.

> Eg,In Java
>
> ```
> int a; 
> foo(a = 20);
> ```

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go which explain basic syntax. (And note that the language is called "Go").

Comment: I know that the language is called "GO" but I did hear around the web that using GoLang on articles makes it easier for people to search about the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this only:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(a int) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
    a := 20
    foo(a)
}
```